# getting started with log4cpp in windows

Tags: c++, logging, visual-studio-2005, log4cpp

I need to do logging in a C++ application. After googling for a while, I decided to use log4cpp.

1. is that a safe option to go with, or is there something better out there?
2. How do I get started with installation and importing it to my application using Windows XP, Visual Studio 2005?

TIA

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've used Log4cpp in the past and it does the job, though bear in mind the project has been inactive since 2007. There are also the following alternatives:

- Apache's [log4cxx](http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/index.html) which is still active.
- Matthew Wilson's [Pantheios](http://www.pantheios.org/) library.
- [Log4cplus](http://log4cplus.sourceforge.net/).

As for getting started, does the documentation not cover this?

Comment: It looks as though there's been some recent work on `log4cpp`. There was a [release 1.1 in November 2012](http://sourceforge.net/projects/log4cpp/files/log4cpp-1.1.x%20%28new%29/).

Comment: [10 years](http://log4cpp.sourceforge.net/#releases) between releases, almost to the day; must be some kind of record.

Answer (score 1):

The framework I'm using, `wxWidgets`, comes with logging features.  The logging is easy and comes in different flavors (such as debug only and logging by priorities).  `wxWidgets` comes with installation instructions, search on 'MSW'.

Which ever system you choose, you may want to standardize you log output.  Creating an output format that can be imported into a database or spreadsheet can be very helpful.