# Is there a good c++ logger available for unix platform that does not require installation

Tags: c++, logging

I was looking for a logging library for c++ on the unix platform which does not require installing library on the machine. Something similar to pugixml library for xml parsing.

Answer (score 0):

You may always use the standard `syslog` C API. If you require more sophisticated features, you could also consider [log4cpp](http://log4cpp.sourceforge.net/).

Edit: It seems that i confused log4cpp which is inactive with log4cxx from apache. But they seem both to do the job just fine. [log4cxx](http://logging.apache.org/log4cxx/index.html)

See also following question for alternatives: [Getting started with log4cpp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2209134/getting-started-with-log4cpp-in-windows)

Comment: log4cpp requires user to install using make . What I want is just .h and .cpp files that can be ready to use.

Comment: How about linking it statically? Here is a link to someone using it this way: http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/logging-log4cxx-user/200601.mbox/%3CAFB9C79911CD10479EA1DAA9C222798403485AF0@sntmail2.corp.oocl.com%3E

Comment: I went through log4cxx but like I said it requires installation which is not what I want. Also I have specified unix platform in the question and the link that you have given is for windows

Comment: What dependecies are allowed?

Comment: You could also consider boost log, but i have no experience with this library at all. It seems to support static linking more easily.  http://boost-log.sourceforge.net/libs/log/doc/html/log/installation.html